# BIg Query Join from UNNEST Value Analytics

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have google analytics tables in big query:

| event_id | event_params.key | event_params.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123324 | retailerId | abc123 |
| .... | priority | high |

I have a sales table:

| retailerId | sale_date | sale_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 10/01/2022 | 5 |
| abc123 | 10/01/2022 | 3 |

What I'd like to be able to do is produce the following output:

| priority | sum(sales) |
| --- | --- |
| high | 8 |

I can't seem to figure out how to join this data correctly:

```
with sales_totals as (
  select
  retailerId,
  sum(sale_amount) as earnings
  from `sales`
  group by 1
)

SELECT 
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'priority') as priority,
earnings
FROM `analytics.events_*` 
join sales_totals on sales_totals.retailerId = (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'retailerId')
where event_name = 'sale_event'
and retailerId is not null
group by 1, 2
order by 2 desc
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with flattening the events table; after that all joins will become trivial.

```
-- Generating some test events
with test_events as 
(
  select 123324 as event_id
    , 
    [
      struct('retailerId' as `key`, 'high_priority_retailer' as `value`)
      , struct('priority' as `key`, 'high' as `value`)
    ] as event_params

  union all

  select 1233241 as event_id
    , 
    [
      struct('retailerId' as `key`, 'another_high_priority_retailer' as `value`)
      , struct('priority' as `key`, 'high' as `value`)
    ] as event_params

  union all

  select 6666 as event_id
    , 
    [
      struct('retailerId' as `key`, 'low_priority_retailer' as `value`)
      , struct('priority' as `key`, 'low' as `value`)
    ] as event_params

  union all

  select 9999 as event_id
    , 
    [
      struct('retailerId' as `key`, 'medium_priority_retailer' as `value`)
      , struct('priority' as `key`, 'medium' as `value`)
    ] as event_params
)

-- We can unnest parameters and after that aggregate them, to create a flat table
, agg_variant as 
(
  select e.event_id
    , max(if(params.key = 'retailerId', params.value, null)) as retailer_id
    , max(if(params.key = 'priority', params.value, null)) as priority
  from test_events e
  cross join unnest (e.event_params) as params
  group by 1
)

-- We can unnest parameters and after that pivot them, to create a flat table
, pivot_variant as 
(
  select *
  from 
  (
    select e.event_id, params.*
    from test_events e
    cross join unnest (e.event_params) as params
  )
  pivot
  (
    max(value)
    for key in ('retailerId', 'priority')
  )
)

-- Generating some test sales
, test_sales as 
(
  select 'high_priority_retailer' as retailerId, '1900-01-01', 10000 as sale_amount
  union all
  select 'high_priority_retailer' as retailerId, '1900-01-02', 10000 as sale_amount
  union all
  select 'another_high_priority_retailer' as retailerId, '1900-01-01', 10000 as sale_amount
  union all
  select 'another_high_priority_retailer' as retailerId, '1900-01-02', 10000 as sale_amount
  union all
  select 'low_priority_retailer' as retailerId, '1900-01-02', 100 as sale_amount
  union all
  select 'medium_priority_retailer' as retailerId, '1900-01-02', 1000 as sale_amount
)

, agg_sales as 
(
  select retailerId, sum(sale_amount) as sales
  from test_sales
  group by 1
)

, retailers_list as
(
  select distinct retailerId, priority
  from pivot_variant
)

select rl.priority, sum(s.sales) as sales
from retailers_list rl
inner join agg_sales s on s.retailerId = rl.retailerId
group by 1
```

Comment: Added agg_sales and retailers_list CTE to eliminate possible duplicates.